# find all matched elements of an previously unknown element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Not Sure if I'm missing the obvious here, but have gotten myself in a spin trying to work this out.

I want to find the first child of a container, and then either return its element or class  and use that to grab any other top level matching elements in that container.

for example

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#">The First Element</a>
    <div><p> some content with a <a href="#">link that should not be included</a></div>
    <h2>a heading</h2>
    <p>this is some content</p>
    <a href="#">This link should be found by the search</a>
</div>
```

so I would like to use jQuery to find out what that first child is (in this case an 'a' tag) and then search for any matching elements, I'd prefer to get only the direct decendants back, any ideas?

EDIT :  Thanks for the great responses  -  I think the first thing I was missing was the .prop method, will have to test a couple of the solutions out to see which fits the best....  update coming soon.

Comment: The second 'a' that you want is not a descendant of the first 'a' - it is a sibling.

Comment: Your first `<p>` does not have a closing tag, is that intended?

Comment: <p> end tag can also be omited in some circumstances

Comment: the markup was a bit slap dash I'll admit but more to illustrate a simple markup context for the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear so here are some options:  I turn the background lime just to demonstrate on the first few.

All the siblings of that first link then:

```
$('a:first').siblings().css('background-color', 'lime');
```

All the siblings of the first element inside the box:

```
$('.box>:first').siblings().css('background-color', 'lime');
```

All the siblings of the first `a` element inside the box

```
$('.box>:first(a)').siblings().css('background-color', 'lime');
```

NOW, Something a BIT more complex, stuff matching this first element:

```
$('.box>:first').each(function () {
  //if it has a single class we can do this
  var myclass = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
  // use that single class above
  $(this).siblings(myclass).css('background-color', 'blue');

  //find elements with the same tag that are siblings of my element
  $(this).siblings(this.tagName).css('background-color', 'lime');

  //handle multiple classes
  var myclassAll = $(this).attr('class');

  //split the multiple classes, then use it
  var myclassList = myclassAll.split(" ");
  $(this).siblings().each(function () {
    var iam = $(this);// each sibling
    $.each(myclassList, function (i) {
      if (iam.hasClass(myclassList[i])) {
        iam.addClass(myclassList[i] + 'New');//add new class on matches
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the most extensive answer and and covers all aspects of my question, thank you very much for awesome input, though for the particular problem I was solving I have actually used @undefined 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $box = $('.box'), 
    $first = $box.children().first(),
    type = $first.prop('localName'),
    $matching = $box.children(type);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8hgP/

Comment: Thanks for this, while I Mark Schultheisis above answer the most correct - which I believe it is, I've used your solution to solve the actual problem I was dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fc= jQuery(".box>:first-child").eq(0); //is the first child of container
var allE = fc.parent().children(fc.prop("tagName")); //contains all elements with tagname equal to fc's
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/xyK72/

```
var selectedElement = $('.box > :first-child').prop('tagName');
$('.box > :first-child').siblings(selectedElement).addClass('highlight');
```

Note that you are looking for a sibling, not a descendant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var first_element = $(".box *:first-child").prop("tagName");
alert( first_element  );
```

Note >>>    ***:first-child** it takes first HTML tags from selector